# Full file date (without GNU utilities)

Tags: shell, ls, timestamps

I am trying to obtain the full date (created or modified) of a particular file for passing to another program. I have tried variations of options with the ls command but none provide a full date for files less than 6 months old and I have limit usage of the options. When I try certain options I have seen trying to research this I get the following message:

```
usage: ls [-1ACFHLNRabcdefgilmnopqrstuxEUX] [File...]
```

None of which seems to provide what I needs as far as I can tell so I tried to use the stat command but it is not available to me.

I am using the Korn shell on AIX 5.3 which has limited commands available, can anyone suggest another way that I might be able to obtain a file's created or modified date as a full date (either dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas My apologies for not knowing that. It is my first time using Unix and I only know that I use PuTTY to log in and the shell is korn. How would I find out what the OS is?

Comment: `uame -rs` returned `AIX 3`

Comment: For older files, it should still give you the full _date_ (year, month and day), just not the time. It's for newer files that it wouldn't give you the year.

Comment: AIX 3? AIX 3.2 1992 / AIX 3.1, February 1990 / AIX 3.0 1989  - that's going some!

Can you try `oslevel` just in case that uname doesn't give what you might expect?

Comment: @EightBitTony `oslevel` returns `5.3.0.0`

Comment: So, AIX 5.3 - much less worrying, doesn't affect your answer, but does calm my nerves a bit (5.3 is long out of support obviously, but not as bad as AIX 3 would have been!).  For reference, oslevel is the approved method of getting the version of out AIX.  `man oslevel` for all the flags.

Comment: @EightBitTony unfortunately `man` also does not work on the version I have access to :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `ls`, though you may not always be able to get the *time*, you should be able to derive the *date* (year, month and day of the month).

In the C locale, the date output in `ls -l` should either be `Mmm dd HH:MM` for recent files (and you should be able to derive the year (either this year or the previous one) or `Mmm dd  YYYY` for older files or files with a modification time in the future. So you should always be able to get the date (YYYY-mm-dd) out of that:

```
eval "$(date +'year=%Y month=%m')"
LC_ALL=C ls -dln file | awk -v y="$year" -v m="$month" '{
  month = index("--JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", $6) / 3
  day = $7
  if ($8 ~ /:/)
    year = y - (month > m)
  else
    year = $8
  printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\n", year, month, day
  exit}'
```

---

Now, if you want the full modification time with maximum precision, I'm afraid there is no standard command for that.

You'll find some `ls` implementations that have options for that (`ls --full-time` with GNU `ls` or `-D <format>` with FreeBSD `ls` for instance)

There exist a number of different and incompatible implementations of a `stat` command (IRIX, `zsh` builtin, GNU, BSD) that can give you that.

Or you could use the `-printf` predicate of GNU `find`. Or the `-r` option of GNU `date`.

Not all implementations will give you sub-second granularity. And beware of time zones and DST as depending on the format you choose and the timezone you're in, a given output may be ambiguous and refer to more than one possible date.

For symlinks, you may also want to ask yourself whether it's the modification time of the link or its target you're after. Some of the options mentioned here will do one or the other by default and some of them can be told to do one or the other on demand.

- `zsh` stat: `stat -F '%Y-%m-%d %T.%N %z' +mtime file`
  ↳`1992-05-13 14:57:00.123368710 +0100`
- GNU `stat`: `stat -c %y file`
  ↳`1992-05-13 14:57:00.123368710 +0100`
- BSD `stat`: `stat -t '%F %T %z' -f %Sm file`
  ↳`1992-05-13 14:57:00 +0100`
- IRIX `stat`: `stat -m file`
- GNU `find`: `find file -prune -printf '%TF %TT %Tz\n'`
  ↳`1992-05-13 14:57:00.1233687100 +0100`
- GNU `date`: `date -r file '+%F %T.%N %z'`
  ↳`1992-05-13 14:57:00.123368710 +0100`
- FreeBSD `ls`: `ls -D '[%F %T %z]' -l file`
  ↳`-r-xr-xr-x  2 bin  bin  372298 [1992-05-13 14:57:00 +0100] file`
- GNU `ls`: `ls --full-time -l file`
  ↳`-r-xr-xr-x 2 bin bin 372298 1992-05-13 14:57:00.123368710 +0100 file`
- ast-open `ls`: `ls -Z '%(mtime:time=%F %T.%N %z)s'`
  ↳`1992-05-13 14:57:00.123368710 +0100`

AIX, which your `ls` synopsis suggests you may be using has an [`istat`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/istat.htm) command ([AIX 5.3 man page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/istat.htm?cp=ssw_aix_53%2F1-2-0-8-55)) that displays dates in full (without sub-second granularity, and ambiguous unless you force `TZ` to `UTC0`), though not that easy to parse:

```
$ LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0 istat file
Inode 10360 on device 10/6    File
Protection: r-xr-xr-x
Owner: 2(bin)     Group: 2(bin)
Link count: 2     Length 372298 bytes

Last updated:  Wed May 13 14:08:13 1992
Last modified: Wed May 13 13:57:00 1992
Last accessed: Sun Jan 31 15:49:23 1993
```

Also note that for symlinks, you'll get the date of the target of the symlink, not the symlink itself.

If you don't have access to any of those, your best bet for portability may be `perl`:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T %z", localtime((lstat(shift))[9]))' file
1992-05-13 14:57:00 +0100
```

Note that few systems have a *creation time* for files (sometimes called *birth time*), and there's no standard API, let alone command to query it, so the situation is even worse than for the modification time.

Comment: Hi Stéphane, the only thing that worked was your suggestion of perl. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `ls`:

```
ls --time-style=long-iso -l
```

or

```
ls --time-style=+FMT -l
```

where FMT follows `date` command format. In your case:

```
ls --time-style=+%Y/%m/%d -l
```

Comment: Hi JJoao, sadly this does not work as the only options I am able to use are those shown in my question. I get the following when I try your method: pgms>ls --time-style=+%Y/%m/%d -l
ls: illegal option -- -
ls: illegal option -- -
ls: illegal option -- y
ls: illegal option -- =
ls: illegal option -- +
ls: illegal option -- %
ls: illegal option -- Y
ls: illegal option -- /
ls: illegal option -- %
ls: illegal option -- /
ls: illegal option -- %
usage: ls [-1ACFHLNRabcdefgilmnopqrstuxEUX] [File...]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a POSIX function to do that:

```bsh
mtime() {
   touch -r "$1" /etc/fstab
   diff -u /etc/fstab /dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -f 2
}
```

Result:

```bsh
$ mtime ~/.profile
2019-07-01 06:25:34.000000000 -0500
```

http://cup.github.io/autumn/util/path/file-mtime